# Can I copy text from one file by shell?

Tags: shell, clipboard

Can I copy text to the clipboard from one file by shell? and I want to paste it to Browser later.

Comment: search for xclip

Answer (score 4):

You want `xclip`.

```
$ xclip -i -selection clipboard <<< "*foo bar*"
```

*foo bar*

Comment: the -i switch is optional i seem to remember

Comment: @ixtmixilix: Sure. But it doesn't hurt to be explicit.